# Efficiently checking anagrams?

Tags: c, algorithm

What is the most efficient way of checking if 2 strings (represented by const char *) are anagrams or not? I know we can sort and then compare. But, sorting is nlogn.

Thanks for the help.

EDIT: I got a vote down for not showing my attempt. So, my attempt is following:

```
int anagram(const char * c1, const char *c2){
 char *s1=my_sort(c1);
 char *s2=my_sort(c2);
 return strcmp(s1,s2)==0?1:0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is from one of my blog posts :)

```
/**
* Works for 0-127 ASCII string
**/
int isanagram(const char* s1,const char* s2){
    int hash[128];
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<128;i++)
        hash[i]=0;
    while(*s1) hash[*s1++]++;
    while(*s2) hash[*s2++]--;
    for(i=0;i<128;i++)
        if(hash[i]) return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

Explanation: Every char in the alphabet has a position in the hash table. For each char in s1 we increment the count for that char and for each char in s2 we decrement the count for the char in the hash table. if all of the char has 0 count at the end then both s1 and s2 have same number of each char, which is the definition of anagram.

Complexity: O(n) if n>128 , where n is the max of length of s1 and s2

Comment: You can avoid the initializer loop with     `int hash[128]={0};`

Comment: I'm not a fan of semi-cryptic code (I do understand the above). This post would profit from some explanation regarding why and how this works and the intuition behind it, and less focus on "lemme see how many clock cycles and LOC I really need for this".

Comment: I edited the post with Explanation and Complexity @ G. Bach. Thanks :) @ KingsIndian

Comment: There is no reason to say it's `O(n)` if `n > 128`... it's just `O(n)`